# The maximum nametable character count quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

When I am trying to read a meta data I got this error any Idea here is My code

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue; // DPNote: This may actually be too big.  see how it performs.
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 99999999;

MetadataExchangeClientMode exchangeMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet; // Default to a HttpGET
metaClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(binding);
metaClient.MaximumResolvedReferences = 10 * 100; //DPNote: Some arbitrary number.  Default is 10, so this is bigger.


if (address.Scheme == "http")
  exchangeMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;
else if (address.Scheme == "https")
  exchangeMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;
else
  exchangeMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange;

MetadataSet metadata = metaClient.GetMetadata(address, exchangeMode);
MetadataImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metadata);
```

and this is the line which throws the error

```
MetadataSet metadata = metaClient.GetMetadata(address, exchangeMode);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing 'Update Reference' through visual studio, add these lines to devenv.exe.config

```
<system.serviceModel>

 <client>

 <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GenericBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="net.tcp" />

 </client>

 <bindings>

 <netTcpBinding>

 <binding name="GenericBinding"

 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"

 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

 <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"

 maxStringContentLength="2147483647"

 maxArrayLength="2147483647"

 maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"

 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

 <security mode="None" />

 </binding>

 </netTcpBinding>

 </bindings>

 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks! You saved my day (week even) with this solution!

Answer (score 3):

This is a error in Microsoft code,Http-Get not support Reader Quotas, so we can do this

```
      var smAsm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().First(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("System.ServiceModel,"));
        var defTy = smAsm.GetType("System.ServiceModel.Channels.EncoderDefaults");
        var rq = (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas)defTy.GetField("ReaderQuotas", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(null);
        rq.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
        rq.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
        rq.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
        rq.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried incrementing any of these other values inside of `binding.ReaderQuotas` beyond their default values:

maxDepth, maxStringContentLength, maxArrayLength, maxBytesPerRead?

It could also be the maxBufferPoolSize of the `binding`

Comment: Hmm....  Does your server side and client side end points match each other? You might also be missing the mex binding?  Look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d768c591-2b9d-42cb-b27a-9523befe3f0d and here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/38d09aca-acd3-4eb8-a5d3-803a68de92d9/

Comment: I can only check this at client side because meta data can be of any foriegn service..

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be fixed in .NET 4.0. According to Reflector, MetadataExchangeClient now reads the quotas from the supplied binding, and if it doesn't have those, it falls back to EncoderDefaults. Previously, I think it only used EncoderDefaults, that's why @BreakHead's solution seems to be the only solution (to change EncoderDefaults with reflection).